# How would I make it so that whenever a non-integer value is entered, it will tell the user to enter an integer value? Java - NetBeans

Tags: java

I'm making a very simple program that asks a user to input an age and then it will calculate a charge for admission. So far all works well but I'm wanting to add a check in so that if the user inputs anything other than an int value, it will ask them to enter an int value. I.e if they enter a character.

Here is my code:

```
public class CalcChargeAge {
    public static void main(String[] args) {       
        
            int x;
            double chargeA = 20;
            double chargeB = 10;
            
            
            System.out.println("Enter Users age to calculate charge for entry. ");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            x = in.nextInt();

            if (x >= 18) {
                System.out.println("Users age is " + x);
                System.out.println("Please pay the charge for entry: £" + chargeA);
            } else if (x >= 12) {
                System.out.println("Users age is " + x);
                System.out.println("Please pay the charge for entry: £" + chargeB);  
            } else {
                System.out.println("Users age is " + x);
                System.out.println("User entry charge is free. Print admission ticket.");
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can use [`in.hasNextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt())

Comment: Add a `try { ... } catch(...) { ... }` around your `in.nextInt()` call. Then you can handle the case when the input was not of type integer.

Comment: Input a String using nextLine() and try to parse it using Integer.parseInt().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Scanner.hasNextInt()` method to check whether the input is an integer, which I think is a lot nicer than catching an exception.

Then for the full implementation you could wrap everything in a loop, so you could do something like:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

while(in.hasNext()) {

    if(in.hasNextInt()) {

        int x = in.nextInt();
        // Handle input
        break;
    }
    else {

        // Handle invalid input
        in.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: But then you should say what to do when hasNextInt returns false.

Comment: Clarified my answer

Comment: It’s been that long, I’d forgotten about loops, oh d

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways (beware, it might not be the best or even the good one) to go about it would be to replace `x=in.nextInt();` with

```
            while(true) {
              String input = in.next();
              try {
                x = Integer.parseInt(input);
                break;
              } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Please provide an integer!"); 
              }
            }
```

this will not leave the loop until user provides an integer value (evil!)

Comment: what are they disliking? :) I've posted a working solution.. maybe not the best one, but it's certainly is not "not useful"

Comment: anyway, if there's any convention on how to properly post solutions to such questions, I'd be happy to learn it

Comment: It was not me who disliked the answer, but I assume you got a downvote because you did not explain what you write.
Posting only the code as an answer is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work fine:

```
boolean isValid = false;
int validInput = 0;
while (!isValid) {
    try {
        validInput = scanner.nextInt();
        isValid = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid integer.");
    }
}
// ... code using validInput
```